# Syncing Time in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, time

I am trying to sync time between two android devices. The precision has to be upto 5 ms. The gps and network time werent this precise so i thought about sharing time between the devices over the local network and syncing the time using PTP(Precision time protocol).
Now as i can't change the time on non-rooted devices so i thought about saving the time difference shared by device and kept on showing the time to user in a textview.
Now the textview needed to be updated every one ms so the user can see the time in ms too.
I am updating the textview in a thread which is updated every ms.

```
class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
    // @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                setCurrentTime();
                Thread.sleep(1); // Pause of 1/100 Second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the problem comes that after syncing the time , the time diff is less then 5 ms but after some time of syncing the time starts to drift a part and after 10-15 mins the time diff is more then 1 sec.
So any ideas on how to rectify this issue?

Comment: "Now the textview needed to be updated every one ms so the user can see the time in ms too" -- first, humans are not capable of viewing 1000 changes per second. Second, Android is not a real-time operating system. `Thread.sleep()` will not return in precisely the number of milliseconds you request, because the CPU may be busy executing other threads.

Comment: I have tried updating the UI after every one second but still the drift is there , seems like making thread.sleep(1000) works more like thread.sleep(1003 or 1004) and these changes keep on adding up to make a bigger drift.
Even using Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); won't help me?

Answer (score 0):

> seems like making thread.sleep(1000) works more like thread.sleep(1003 or 1004) and these changes keep on adding up to make a bigger drift

As I noted, Android is not a RTOS.

Moreover, you should not care whether `sleep()` returns in 1003 or 1004 milliseconds. You seem to be combining two things:

- Determining how much time has elapsed since you synchronized the time
- Displaying the current synchronized time

**These have nothing to do with each other**.

Use your `sleep()` loop -- or, better yet, `postDelayed()` for greater efficiency -- **only** to get control **roughly** every second to know that you need to update the `TextView`.

To determine what value to show in the `TextView`, do not add some assumed amount of time based on the `sleep()`. Instead:

- When you get the synchronized time value from the other device, also save [the current value of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29)
- To determine how much time in milliseconds has elapsed since the synchronization, subtract the saved value of `elapsedRealtime()` from the current value of calling `elapsedRealtime()`

Comment: What if i try to find time between execution of thread and then subtract that time , will that help?

Comment: And yes updating UI every millisecond is not a good idea so i am going to update it every 100 ms